# Loss of trig precision

Tags: c++, precision, trigonometry

For a gravity simulation, I need to find the angle between two objects so I can apply the force. However, I am losing precision and I don't know where. Here is the minimal code that can reproduce the issue.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Vector2f
{
    float x, y;
};

Vector2f operator-(Vector2f& left, Vector2f& right)
{
    return Vector2f{ left.x - right.x, left.y - right.y };
}

double pi = 3.141592653589793238463;

double angle(Vector2f& one, Vector2f& two)
{
    Vector2f normal(one - two);

    if (!normal.x && !normal.y)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    float theta = -(atan((double)(normal.y / normal.x)) - pi / 2);

    if (normal.x < 0)
    {
        return (theta - pi / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return (theta + pi / 2);
    }

} 

int main()
{
    Vector2f one{ 0,0 };
    for (int i = -100; i <= 100; i += 100)
    {
        for (int j = -100; j <= 100; j += 100)
        {
            Vector2f two{ i,j };
            cout << i << ", " << j << endl;
            cout << "sin:\t" << sin(angle(one, two)) * 180.0f / pi << endl;
            cout << "cos:\t" << cos(angle(one, two)) * 180.0f / pi << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For instance, where I should be getting 45 (comparing (0,0) with (100, -100) due to the grid), I am getting answers like 40.5142 and 57.2958. I understand if the precision lost were less than a degree, but this is ridiculous. I want all the output from this code to be multiples of 45, basically for those without trig knowledge. Changing the datatype of Vector2f to double does not affect the end result. Could you help me find the issue?

I am using VS 2015, but it happens similarly on VS 2013.

Comment: Please provide the specific inputs and outputs you are providing/seeing that you don't like.  Or, I guess a specific value of i/j in your loops that gives an undesired answer.  Remember, [mcve]  - emphasis on minimal.

Comment: Output formatting problems?

Comment: Two more thoughts: (1) look into the applicability of `atan2()` instead of `atan()`. (2) avoid conversions between radians and degrees (or vice-versa) as much as you can.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What are the issues? on VS, I am getting fine output format

coordinate x, coordinate y
sin :            sin-value
cos:            cos-value

Comment: A float really isn't precise enough for general-purpose numerical work. It's a fast type for gross modelling, eg 3D meshes or colour channels in images.

Comment: @xaxxon sorry, I assumed you people knew trig :/

1) -100, -100 should yield 45 and -45, but I get 40 and -40
2) 0, -100 should give 45 and 0, but instead yields 57 and 0
I want all of the numbers to be steps of 45, basically

Comment: Please review [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Jeff The more effort you put into the question and the less effort it takes to answer the question, the more likely you are to get help.

Comment: You may want to have a constant for PI/2.0.  No need to calculate every time.

Comment: @xaxxon I get it. I've been working with trig since I was 15 and forgot most people have little idea of how it works.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Which float is the problem? Because being off by 10-20% is not rounding error

Comment: @Jeff:  I believe the issue is that you are using `float` instead of `double`.  Also, I don't think that `!normal.y` will work all the time, as an exact zero value is hard to achieve.  Generally, `float` is used in space constrained systems (e.g. embedded systems); the libraries are designed to handle `double`, so keep everything in `double`.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  What are the optimization settings?  Is the compiler generating any instructions for H/W floating point support?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ok, but where do you see the issue with floats and doubles? a float has ~20 bits of precision, which should be around 6 digits of precision, yet my numbers are off by 10-20%

Comment: What is 180/pi?

Comment: Constant for radian -> degree conversion.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(atan(1))+in+degrees  You're not doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: You essentially have `convert_to_degrees(sin(atan(X)))` Working from the inside, out: atan gives an angle.  sin takes an angle and gives the value on the y axis corresponding to the radius at that angle on a unit circle.  You are trying to convert a distance to degrees.  Always gotta keep track of your units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sin(angle(one, two)) * 180.0f / pi` doesn't make sense.

it should be

```
sin(angle(one, two))
```

And you may print your angle

```
std::cout << angle(one, two)) * 180.0f / pi << " degree\n";
std::cout << angle(one, two)) << " radian\n";
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. @xaxxon also found it around the same time. Thanks guys.

Comment: Note that we shouldn't need trigonometry here, since `sin (atan2 (y, x) = y / hypot (x, y)` and `cos (atan2 (y, x)) = x / hypot (x, y)`.